# Конструктор Tilda - пропадает кнопка

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть сайт, сделанный в конструкторе `Тильда`, в него интегрирован магазин на основе `Эквида`. Я добавила кнопки с помощью js и вставила их на страницу товара.

Вот, например [страница с товаром](https://topteas.ru/tea#!/p/82047252). У нее есть кнопка Оставить заявку. 
[Здесь](https://topteas.ru/tea#!/p/81186117) есть кнопка Купить в один клик.

Эти две кнопки добавлены через конструктор Тильда, но вставлены в блок Эквида. Проблема в том, что если вернуться в категорию Чай и снова зайти в этот товар, то кнопка исчезает и появляется снова только если обновить страницу.

*Например*: Узбекский чай - есть кнопка Купить в один клик. Заходим по хлебным крошкам в Чай и снова выбираем Узбекский или любой другой - кнопки нет. Обновляем страницу - кнопка появилась. Аналогично с кнопкой Оставить заявку. В чем может быть проблема? Техподдержка никак не помогла.
Вот код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function triggerClick() {
        $("#mylink").trigger("click");   
    }
    function triggerClick2() {
        $("#mylink2").trigger("click");
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            if ($('.product-details__product-options').length && !$('.mylink').length) {
                $('.product-details__product-options').append('<div onclick="triggerClick()" class="mylink"><span>Купить в один клик</span></div>');
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            if ($('.product-details__product-options').length && !$('.mylink2').length) {
                $('.product-details__product-options').append('<div onclick="triggerClick2()" class="mylink2"><span>Оставить заявку</span></div>');
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 300);        
    });
</script>
```

Comment: а зачем вы это все через `setInterval` делаете?

Comment: Смею предположить, что при повторном заходе не срабатывает событие `$(document).ready`. Поскольку вы все равно используете `setInterval`, то можете попробовать убрать `$(document).ready` вообще. И не очищать `clearInterval`

Comment: @teran, если честно, эту функцию написал другой программист, я только вторую кнопку добавила. Без setInterval не работает ничего и я не знаю почему. В смысле, вообще ничего. Перенести блок в другое место, добавить кнопку, добавить стиль в зависимости от условий - все работает только в этой функции. Если вы знаете другой способ, то  буду рада узнать ваш вариант.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, этот вариант сработал, но полетел остальной скрипт. Как я написала выше, весь код срабатывает только в функции setInterval, поэтому если я вставляю блок и нет clearInterval, то он теперь вставляется бесконечно. Но кнопки всегда на месте)

Comment: Поэтому в `setInterval` надо проверить, есть ли уже необходимые вам элементы. Если есть, то ничего не надо делать. Ну а если элементов нету, то их надо вставить!

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, не совсем понимаю вас. Вот что получилось у меня - [ссылка](http://project704387.tilda.ws/?store-page=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-p90820406&category=22539024&offset=0&sort=normal) , тут код - [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/fkvwjLq3/)

Comment: Что и где нужно добавить или убрать, чтобы добавляемый блок не добавлялся бесконечно?

Comment: Гммм... Вам надо разобраться с программированием хотя бы на базовом уровне) Посмотрите вот здесь http://jsfiddle.net/m48Lqeby/